# How to detect form submit complete

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, form-submit, access-denied

I want to be able to submit a form with a file and detect when the form has successfully been submitted. I have looked all over online and have also tried the AJAX solution to the problem with "ajaxSubmit". Of course "ajaxSubmit" works in all browsers but IE (go figure). I also understand that that IE prohibits this for security reasons and that is why I am getting the "access denied error". however, I am wondering if there is a possible solution to this problem (I know this question has been asked many times, but I have not seen a solution thus far). Any help would be great!